# How can I get a stored procedure to create 2 temporary tables and send 2 emails from the separate tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure which creates 1 temporary table populates and then emails the results through if it is above a certain threshold. I am wanting to alter this so that if the results are above the same threshold it runs SP_WhO3 and emails me the results through?

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
DECLARE @QueryValue INT,
        @QueryValue2 INT,
        @EmailList NVARCHAR(255),
        @EmailList2 NVARCHAR(255),
        @CellList NVARCHAR(255),
        @HTML NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @HTML2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ServerName NVARCHAR(50),
        @EmailSubject NVARCHAR(100),
        @LastDateStamp DATETIME;

SELECT @LastDateStamp = MAX(DateStamp)
FROM [dbWarden].dbo.CPUStatsHistory;

SELECT @ServerName = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), SERVERPROPERTY('servername'));

SELECT @QueryValue = CAST(Value AS INT)
FROM [dbWarden].dbo.AlertSettings
WHERE VariableName = 'QueryValue'
      AND AlertName = 'CPUAlert'
      AND [Enabled] = 1;

SELECT @QueryValue2 = CAST(Value AS INT)
FROM [dbWarden].dbo.AlertSettings
WHERE VariableName = 'QueryValue2'
      AND AlertName = 'CPUAlert'
      AND [Enabled] = 1;

SELECT @EmailList = EmailList,
       @EmailList2 = EmailList2,
       @CellList = CellList
FROM [dbWarden].dbo.AlertContacts
WHERE AlertName = 'CPUAlert';

CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    [SQLProcessPercent] INT,
    [SystemIdleProcessPercent] INT,
    [OtherProcessPerecnt] INT,
    DateStamp DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #TEMP
EXEC [dbWarden].dbo.usp_CPUStats;

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #TEMP
    WHERE SQLProcessPercent > @QueryValue
          AND DateStamp > COALESCE(@LastDateStamp, GETDATE() - 1)
)
BEGIN

    SET @HTML
        = N'<html><head><style type="text/css">
        table { border: 0px; border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;}
        th {color:#FFFFFF; font-size:12px; font-family:arial; background-color:#7394B0; font-weight:bold;border: 0;}
        th.header {color:#FFFFFF; font-size:13px; font-family:arial; background-color:#41627E; font-weight:bold;border: 0;}
        td {font-size:11px; font-family:arial;border-right: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;padding: 5px 5px 5px 8px;}
        </style></head><body>
        <table width="700"> <tr><th class="header" width="700">High CPU Alert</th></tr></table> 
        <table width="700">
        <tr>  
        <th width="150">SQL Percent</th>    
        <th width="150">System Idle Percent</th>  
        <th width="150">Other Process Percent</th>  
        <th width="200">Date Stamp</th>
        </tr>';
    SELECT @HTML
        = @HTML + N'<tr>
        <td bgcolor="#E0E0E0" width="150">' + CAST(SQLProcessPercent AS NVARCHAR)
          + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="150">' + CAST(SystemIdleProcessPercent AS NVARCHAR)
          + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E0E0E0" width="150">' + CAST(OtherProcessPerecnt AS NVARCHAR)
          + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="200">' + CAST(DateStamp AS NVARCHAR) + N'</td> 
        </tr>'
    FROM #TEMP
    WHERE SQLProcessPercent > @QueryValue
          AND DateStamp > COALESCE(@LastDateStamp, GETDATE() - 1);

    SELECT @HTML = @HTML + N'</table></body></html>';

    SELECT @EmailSubject = N'[dbWarden]High CPU Alert on ' + @ServerName + N'!';

    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'SQLAdmins',
                              @recipients = @EmailList,
                              @copy_recipients = @EmailList2,
                              @subject = @EmailSubject,
                              @body = @HTML,
                              @body_format = 'HTML';

    --IF @CellList IS NOT NULL
    --BEGIN
    --  /*TEXT MESSAGE*/
    --  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TEMP WHERE SQLProcessPercent > COALESCE(@QueryValue2, @QueryValue))
    --  BEGIN
    --      SET @HTML =
    --          '<html><head></head><body><table><tr><td>CPU,</td><td>Idle,</td><td>Other,</td><td>Date</td></tr>'
    --      SELECT @HTML =  @HTML +   
    --          '<tr><td>' + CAST(SQLProcessPercent AS NVARCHAR) +',</td><td>' + CAST(SystemIdleProcessPercent AS NVARCHAR) +',</td><td>' + CAST(OtherProcessPerecnt AS NVARCHAR) +',</td><td>' + CAST(DateStamp AS NVARCHAR) + '</td></tr>'
    --      FROM #TEMP WHERE SQLProcessPercent > COALESCE(@QueryValue2, @QueryValue)

    --      SELECT @HTML =  @HTML + '</table></body></html>'

    --      SELECT @EmailSubject = '[dbWarden]HighCPUAlert-' + @ServerName

    --      EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
    --      @recipients= @CellList,
    --      @subject = @EmailSubject,
    --      @body = @HTML,
    --      @body_format = 'HTML'

    --  END
    --END
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP2
    (
        SPID INT,
        [Blk By] INT,
        [Elapsed MS] INT,
        CPU INT,
        [I/O Reads] INT,
        [I/O Writes] INT,
        Executions INT,
        [Command Type] VARCHAR(255),
        [Last Wait Type] VARCHAR(100),
        [Object Name] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
        [SQL Statement] NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [Status] NVARCHAR(20),
        [Login] NVARCHAR(100),
        Host NVARCHAR(50),
        DBNAME NVARCHAR(50),
        [Start Time] NVARCHAR(250),
        protocol VARCHAR(50),
        [Transaction Isolation] VARCHAR(50),
        [Connection Writes] NVARCHAR(250),
        [Connection Reads] NVARCHAR(250),
        [Client address] NVARCHAR(50),
        [Authentication] NVARCHAR(25),
        [Date Time Snapshot] NVARCHAR(250),
        [Plan Handle] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

    INSERT INTO #TEMP2
    EXEC dbo.sp_who3;

    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT SPID,
               [Blk By],
               [Elapsed MS],
               CPU,
               [I/O Reads],
               [I/O Writes],
               Executions,
               [Command Type],
               [Last Wait Type],
               [SQL Statement],
               Status,
               Login,
               Host,
               DBNAME,
               [Start Time],
               [Client address],
               Authentication,
               [Date Time Snapshot]
        FROM #TEMP2
    )
    BEGIN

        SET @HTML2
            = N'<html><head><style type="text/css">
        table { border: 0px; border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;}
        th {color:#FFFFFF; font-size:12px; font-family:arial; background-color:#7394B0; font-weight:bold;border: 0;}
        th.header {color:#FFFFFF; font-size:13px; font-family:arial; background-color:#41627E; font-weight:bold;border: 0;}
        td {font-size:11px; font-family:arial;border-right: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;padding: 5px 5px 5px 8px;}
        </style></head><body>
        <table width="80000"> <tr><th class="header" width="80000">CPU ALERTS</th></tr></table> 
        <table width="80000">
        <tr> 
        <th width="100">SPID</th>   
        <th width="150">Blk By</th>  
        <th width="200">Elapsed MS</th>  
        <th width="100">CPU</th>    
        <th width="125">I/O Reads</th>
        <th width="125">I/O Writes</th> 
        <th width="100">Executions</th>  
        <th width="100">Command Type</th>  
        <th width="150">Last Wait Type</th> 
        <th width="10000">SQL Statement</th>
        <th width="100">Status</th>  
        <th width="100">Login</th>  
        <th width="150">Host</th>   
        <th width="125">DBNAME</th>
        <th width="150">Start Time</th>
        <th width="100">Client Address</th> 
        <th width="100">Authentication</th>  
        <th width="250">Date Time Snapshot</th>     
        </tr>';
        SELECT @HTML2
            = @HTML2 + N'<tr>
        <td bgcolor="#E0E0E0" width="100">' + CAST([SPID] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E0E0E0" width="150">' + CAST([Blk By] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="200">' + CAST([Elapsed MS] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E0E0E0" width="100">' + CAST([CPU] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td> 
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="125">' + CAST([I/O Reads] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="125">' + CAST([I/O Writes] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' + CAST([Executions] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' + CAST([Command Type] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="150">' + CAST([Last Wait Type] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="10000">' + CAST([SQL Statement] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' + CAST([Status] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' + CAST([Login] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="150">' + CAST([Host] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="125">' + CAST([DBNAME] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="150">' + CAST([Start Time] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' + CAST([Client address] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' + CAST([Authentication] AS NVARCHAR)
              + N'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="250">' + CAST([Date Time Snapshot] AS NVARCHAR) + N'</td>
        </tr>'
        FROM #TEMP2;

        SELECT @HTML2 = @HTML2 + N'</table></body></html>';

        SELECT @EmailSubject = N'CPU ALERTS' + N' ' + @ServerName;

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'SQLAdmins',
                                     @recipients = 'censor@cngltd.co.uk',
                                     @subject = @EmailSubject,
                                     @body = @HTML2,
                                     @body_format = 'HTML';
    END;
END;
```

END;

When this runs it fires the emails as expected but the second email (SP_WHO3) is blank. Am I missing something?

Comment: (1) you should always case `nvarchar()` with an explicit length (see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)) and (2) are you guarding against NULLs? To see why (2) is important try `SELECT 'foo' + NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that some value in `#temp2 IS NULL`, this results in eveything returning NULL

Try changing the columns from #temp2 and adding `ISNULL()` functions to change the NULL's to empty strings ''.

If you execute this:

```
SELECT NULL +'MailContent'
```

it returns

```
(No column name)
NULL
```

**Example of changes in your query**

```
SELECT @HTML2
    = @HTML2 + N'<tr>
<td bgcolor="#E0E0E0" width="100">' + ISNULL(CAST([SPID]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#E0E0E0" width="150">' +ISNULL(CAST([Blk By]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="200">' +ISNULL(CAST([Elapsed MS]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#E0E0E0" width="100">' +ISNULL(CAST([CPU]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td> 
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="125">' +ISNULL(CAST([I/O Reads]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="125">' +ISNULL(CAST([I/O Writes]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' +ISNULL(CAST([Executions]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' +ISNULL(CAST([Command Type]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="150">' +ISNULL(CAST([Last Wait Type]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="10000">' +ISNULL(CAST([SQL Statement] AS NVARCHAR(MAX),'')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' +ISNULL(CAST([Status]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' +ISNULL(CAST([Login]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="150">' +ISNULL(CAST([Host]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="125">' +ISNULL(CAST([DBNAME]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="150">' +ISNULL(CAST([Start Time]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' +ISNULL(CAST([Client address]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="100">' +ISNULL(CAST([Authentication]AS NVARCHAR), '')
      + N'</td>
<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="250">' +ISNULL(CAST([Date Time Snapshot]AS NVARCHAR), '') + N'</td>
</tr>'
FROM #TEMP2;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Randi I'll give it a try.